# List of fonts containing selected character

Tags: fonts

On Mac OS X, the Character Viewer (equivalent to Character Map on Ubuntu) has a feature where, when looking at a certain character, it can show a list of all fonts that contain that character. Is there something equivalent on Ubuntu?

The use case is that, for instance, I could click on a Kannada character and see all fonts that cover that character (and presumably, the rest of the Kannada language range).

---

**Edit**: Just for an idea of what I mean, here's a screenshot of Character Viewer on Mac OS X 10.6. The "Containing selected character" is near the bottom of the screen. I seem to remember that this part of the interface was better in 10.5 or 10.4, actually.

[image]

Comment: Make a feature request for the Character Map application, please.

Comment: @Toki: It took me ages to locate the project responsible for Character Map! Anyway, it's called gucharmap, uses Bugzilla, and this feature has [already been asked – in 2007](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=484357). The reporter even contributed a patch. There are even many other similar bugs/requests in [the list](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?product=gucharmap&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED). No progress seems to have been made.

Comment: I see, that really sucks and this is a default app of Ubuntu too... And for future reference, you can easily find the package names use Synaptic or even Software Center by going into details.

Comment: I've also made a feature request to the Ubuntu maintainers, [HERE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gucharmap/+bug/724513)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162305/find-the-best-font-for-rendering-a-codepoint

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Fontmatrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN4jv.png) you can compare font characteristics - In the Font Information - Compare.

[image: Fontmatrix's Font Compare]

PS. I think that feature of Character Viewer on Mac OS X would be an awesome feature request to ask of the fontmatrix developer team.

---

In fact, the interface of Fontmatrix has something even better: you can select the Preview tab and enter a string (containing characters you would like the font to have), and see how it is displayed by each font. So you can scroll through the list of fonts and simultaneously see the fonts' coverage of *all* the interesting characters, instead of just one character at a time. This helps you visually pick out the fonts containing the selected character(s).

In the screenshot below, you can see that "BABEL Unicode Bold" (selected) contains all characters except ṝ and that "Arial Regular" (where the mouse is) contains only a few characters.

[image: Screenshot of Fontmatrix's Preview]

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - thanks for the +1, it would be a great feature for fontmatrix, I have made a feature request for it [here](https://gna.org/bugs/?17785)

Comment: Hey do you mind if I merge my screenshot and description (see my other answer) into this?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - is that possible? I'm not sure I should be taking credit for your answer though...

Comment: That's ok, you were the one who suggested Fontmatrix. :-) And the goal is to have a good answer for any future searchers with the same question, so credit is secondary... I've edited the answer to elaborate. (Someone else had to approve the edit, and has kindly done so.) Thanks again!

Comment: This feature seems gone from the latest version of Fontmatrix, or at least I can't find it any more. I don't even see a "Browse" menu any more.

Comment: Also, Fontmatrix was removed from the Debian repositories in 2017: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=862101

Answer (score 6):

Since I originally asked this question in 2011, the information has become more difficult to find on both Ubuntu (where the previously recommended FontMatrix no longer seems to have the feature) and on macOS.

If one cares about a language in general rather than a specific character, is to use `fc-list` with `:lang`, for example:

```
~% fc-list :lang=kn-in
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansKannadaUI-Regular.ttf: Noto Sans Kannada UI:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansKannada-Bold.ttf: Noto Sans Kannada:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansKannadaUI-Bold.ttf: Noto Sans Kannada UI:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerifKannada-Regular.ttf: Noto Serif Kannada:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Navilu/Navilu.ttf: Navilu:style=Normal
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansKannada-Regular.ttf: Noto Sans Kannada:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-kannada/Lohit-Kannada.ttf: Lohit Kannada:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gubbi/Gubbi.ttf: Gubbi:style=Normal
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerifKannada-Bold.ttf: Noto Serif Kannada:style=Bold
```

For specific characters, I [asked a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287707/get-list-of-all-fonts-containing-a-specific-character) on “Ask Different”; copying here the Python script that I ended up using (it works on both operating systems).

1. Install either the `python-fontconfig` or the `python3-fontconfig` package (or both), depending on whether you prefer to use Python 2 or Python 3.
2. Save the following code into a file called (say) `find_fonts.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def find_fonts(c):
    """Finds fonts containing  the (Unicode) character c."""
    import fontconfig
    fonts = fontconfig.query()
    for path in sorted(fonts):
        font = fontconfig.FcFont(path)
        if font.has_char(c):
            yield path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    search = sys.argv[1]
    char = search.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(search, bytes) else search
    for path in find_fonts(char):
        print(path)
```

3. Run the script with either `python find_fonts.py ಠ` or `python3 find_fonts.py ಠ` replacing `ಠ` with the character you care about.

Example output:

```
$ python3 find_fonts.py ಠ
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gubbi/Gubbi.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Navilu/Navilu.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-kannada/Lohit-Kannada.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansKannada-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansKannada-Regular.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansKannadaUI-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansKannadaUI-Regular.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerifKannada-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerifKannada-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this Unix post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393740/40421), I learned that you can search for fonts that contain a character with `fc-list`. First, you need to know the codepoint for the character. For the character you asked about, I launched the Characters application, and searched for "Kannada letter ba". I clicked on the character, and the info dialog listed the codepoint at the end: "Unicode U+0CAC".

Now, I can use `fc-list`:

```
$ fc-list ":charset=0x0cac"
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Navilu/Navilu.ttf: Navilu:style=Normal
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-kannada/Lohit-Kannada.ttf: Lohit Kannada:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gubbi/Gubbi.ttf: Gubbi:style=Normal
$
```

If you know the decimal codepoint instead of hexadecimal, drop the `0x` prefix.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about `fc-list :lang=kn-in` but didn't know about using `charset=` to query a specific character.